# Is running crystal app.cr the same as crystal run app.cr

Tags: crystal-lang

In the documentation crystal says to build and run with the shortcut command:

```
crystal run app.cr
```

and this won't create a permanent binary.
However I could also just run crystal compiler directly on the file itself like:

```
crystal app.cr
```

without the `run` command. My question is, is there a difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 2):

Upon running `crystal --help` it shows that run is the default command.

```
Usage: crystal [command] [switches] [program file] [--] [arguments]

Command:
    init                     generate a new project
    build                    build an executable
    docs                     generate documentation
    env                      print Crystal environment information
    eval                     eval code from args or standard input
    play                     starts Crystal playground server
    run (default)            build and run program
    spec                     build and run specs (in spec directory)
    tool                     run a tool
    help, --help, -h         show this help
    version, --version, -v   show version

Run a command followed by --help to see command specific information, ex:
    crystal <command> --help
```

Comment: Interestingly, you can't use the "default" command with switches like `crystal run --release myfile.cr` `crystal --release myfile.cr` so I guess the default is "run with no switches" (i.e. debug) else `Error: unknown command: --release` :)